# How to prevent tuples inside tuples?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to do what is shown in the following code

```
repeat = 0
x = "1"

while repeat != 3:
    x = x, x
    repeat = repeat + 1

print(x)
```

However, it outputs:
((('1', '1'), ('1', '1')), (('1', '1'), ('1', '1')))

How can I make it so it outputs:
'1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'

I don't want this exact output this is just an example. Is this possible?

Comment: If you just want your required output, why not: `print(', '.join(["'1'"]*8))`?

Comment: There is no list. With `x, x` you create a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried solving your question like this. I hope it fixes your problem.

```
repeat = 0
x = "1"

while repeat != 3:
    x = x + "," + x 
    repeat += 1

print(x)
```

Basically, concatenating the strings.

Alternative answer:

```
repeat = 0
x = ["1"]

while repeat != 3:
    x = x + x
    repeat = repeat + 1

print(x)
```

If you want a list of size n of just 1s

Here's how I did it:

```
n = 3 
y = ["1"]
x = y*n
print(x)
```

Comment: Getting closer but not quite, I need each one to be its own entry, so it's a list of strings. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

More pythonic way is to use join to get the expected output.
If you want to repeat it N times -

```
N = 8
char = '1'

result = "','".join(char * N)
```

If you want to continue using loop, just concatenate the character instead of creating tuple every time you iterate.